# Pasting item values from scripting dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have a `d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` that it's items are ranges. I would like to paste those items in a blank worksheet and this is the code I have for now :

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Clear

    With LatestRevisions
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A1").Resize(.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(.keys)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B1").Resize(.Count, 21) = Application.Transpose(.Items)
    End With
```

In which `LatestRevisions` is a variable set to my dictionary name `d` and I resize the range B1 to 21 because that is the size of my item ranges.

My problem is that the items are in the wrong direction (column data is in rows and row data is in columns), but if I do not put in the `Application.Transpose`nothing gets pasted.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Edit :
Here is how my dictionary is created and filled

```
 Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
If SearchRng.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Function

For Each Cell In SearchRng

    If Not d.Exists(Cell.Value) Then
        d.Add Cell.Value, Cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 21) 'fetch data from column B:V
    Else
        RevisionInDict = ConvertTextToNumeric(d(Cell.Value).Cells(1).Value)
        Revision = ConvertTextToNumeric(Cell.Offset(0, 1))
        If Revision > RevisionInDict Then
            Set d(Cell.Value) = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 21)
                End If
        End If
    Next

    Set GetLatestRevisions = d
End Function
```

Comment: Do you expect `.Count` number of *rows* or of *columns*?

Comment: I expect `.Count` number of rows and 21 columns + 1 column for the keys, so I would like my table to be `.Count` x 22

Comment: Can you please show either how the `.Items` are filled with the ranges or give an [mcve]?

Comment: Yes please see my edit :)

Comment: @VictorLalonde see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The trick is to double transpose

Imagine the following "Sheet2" which I read the ranges from

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: "Sheet2" contains example data to fill the items.</sup>*

The following code …

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestDictionary()
    Dim Dic As Object
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dic.Add "key1", Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 21)
    Dic.Add "key2", Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 21)
    Dic.Add "key3", Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 1).Resize(1, 21)
    Dic.Add "key4", Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, 1).Resize(1, 21)
    Dic.Add "key5", Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(5, 1).Resize(1, 21)
    Dic.Add "key6", Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(6, 1).Resize(1, 21)


    'output in column A and B
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dic.keys)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Resize(Dic.Count, 21).Value = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Dic.items))
End Sub
```

… produces the following output:

[image]
*<sup>Image 2: "Sheet1" for output of keys in column A and items in column B to V.</sup>*

Comment: Wow as simple as that! Thanks a lot I had tried to double transposed but didn't get the syntax correct I guess :P I works like a charm!